# image inside a link for accessible users

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag, wcag2.0

Say I wanna make a clickable image(say site-logo, or whatever) like so:

```
<a href="theblablasite.com"><img src="logo_or_whatever.png"></a>
```

If I want to make it accessible should I use `aria-label` for link along with `alt` for an image or only `aria-label`?

Also, there's lots of opinions about using title and alt together or not to, what is the right way to do it and why?

Comment: alt text advice in HTML5 may be helpful https://w3c.github.io/html/semantics.html#a-link-or-button-containing-nothing-but-an-image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [HTML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#adef-alt) says:

> The alt attribute must be specified for the IMG

Additionally, what I often see in production is providing an assistive text element that is hidden with CSS for visual users but that will be read aloud by screen readers. More on that here https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C7.html

So, in your example, you might do:

```
<a href="theblablasite.com"><img src="logo_or_whatever.png" alt="Relevant info here"><span class="assitive-text">Relevant info here...</span></a>

.assistive-text { height: 1px; width: 1px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: -10px; }
```

That CSS is from the above W3 reference.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Just found this. Perhaps some will find this useful too: `If the author omitted alternative text from the link image, it would fail Success Criterion 1.1.1 because the text alternative would not serve the same purpose as the graphical link.` source: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H2.html

Comment: I agree with this solution, But I also would point out that typically images that are links should specify in the alt tag: Link to "The Blab Site.com." Typically nowadays, logos link to the homepage so the alt, in that case, would be: "Link to Some website homepage"

Answer (score 7):

The `alt` attribute is mandatory

Note that according to the [H30 technique](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20130905/H30.html) of the WCAG

> When an image is the only content of a link, the text alternative for the image describes the unique function of the link.

You can use `aria-label` to give specific alternative intended to be used by assistive technologies.

For instance:

```
 <a href="http://theblablasite.com/" target="_blank"
     aria-label="Visit The Blabla Site Dot Com (opens in a new window)">
       <img src="logo_or_whatever.png" alt="The Blabla site" /></a>
```

The `title` attribute can be used to give a tooltip for mouse users if you have visual information to give.

```
 <a href="http://theblablasite.com/" target="_blank"
     title="opens in a new window"
     aria-label="Visit The Blabla Site Dot Com (opens in a new window)">
       <img src="logo_or_whatever.png" alt="The Blabla site" />
       <i class="arrow"></i>
 </a>
```

Note, that as this information is not accessible by keyboard only users not using any assistive technology, it can only be used if this comes in complement to any other visual cue (in this example, the title `attribute` can be used to explicit the meaning of a small arrow).

Comment: note: the alt attribute is required except in very particular circumstances, refer to https://w3c.github.io/html/semantics.html#when-a-text-alternative-is-not-available-at-the-time-of-publication

Comment: thanks for the note @SteveFaulkner . I must admit that I totally ignored the *When a text alternative is not available at the time of publication* situation, but I promise you not to tell anyone. It will be become the first argument used by people to omit the `alt` attribute *until later* ;-)

Comment: is specifying both aria label on link and alt on image still recommended? wouldn't only one of them suffice? (empty alt on image if aria label on parent)

Comment: @gaurav5430 This still depends on your need. `alt` is the alternative for the image for anyone, while `aria-label` is the alternative for assistive technologies. Having the same alternative for the two is useless.